# Bad patterns when writing promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm wondering if I'm using bad practices when writing custom promises.

I have the following situation.

```
generateHash(password){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        bcrypt.genSalt(10).then(salt => {
            bcrypt.hash(password, salt).then(hash => {
                resolve(hash)
            }).catch(reject)
        }).catch(reject)
    })
}
```

generateHash() has to return a promise which contains the hashed password.
.genSalt() returns a promise and so does .hash(). What I need is generateHash() to return the promise returned by .hash() but since it's inside .genSalt() such thing doesn't happen. I figured that if the function returns a custom promise and everything sits inside it would work perfectly and it did, but I'm wondering if nesting promises like that is a bad practice and a terrible idea overall.

Another thing that I did is approach it more traditional way by using callbacks like so:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (err, salt) {
            bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function (err, hash) {
                if (err) return reject(err)
                resolve(hash)
            });
        });
    })
```

I'm open to suggestions which way is better and kind of want to stick with promises so ideas on how to do that with promises the best way possible are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to create your own promise when the method you are using already returns a promise. The following code will log the generated hash to the console, without creating a promise by yourself:

```
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt")
function generateHash(password){
    return bcrypt.genSalt(10).then(salt => {
            return bcrypt.hash(password, salt).then(hash => {
                return hash;
            })
        })
}

generateHash("foo").then(v => console.log(v));
```

Note that you need to return the inner function - so basically, the code would boil down to

```
function generateHash(password){
    return bcrypt.genSalt(10).then(salt => bcrypt.hash(password, salt));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you nest promises into promises?

You could just do

```
generateHash(password){
    return bcrypt.genSalt(10)
                 .then(salt => bcrypt.hash(password, salt) )
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes. I should get some sleep. I really don't know how that was not obvious. THANKS GUYS!

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on refactoring this too? :)

`registerUser(newUser){
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    encryption.generateHash(newUser.password)
     .then((hash) => {
      newUser.password = hash
      return User.create(newUser).then(resolve).catch(reject)
     })
     .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
     })
   })
  }`

Comment: Nevermind, fixed it. Going straight to bed. Unbelievable what lack of sleep does to you.